# Pandas can't open a csv file FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am having a hard time opening a csv with `Pandas`. I have tried the example in 'Pandas for Everyone' book, have googled many times and last example was here https://analytics4all.org/2016/05/09/python-read-csv-and-excel-with-pandas/
The python program is in a folder called 'lbcsv' then the csv files are in another folder within that one called csv. I have tried not using full path, placing csv file in same folder as the program, then moving them to another folder in the same directory. Just does not seem to want to open the csv. I have tried without the encoding and sep. Before this I had to uninstall `pandas` and `numpy` then reinstall because it was giving an error about `numpy`. I have got around this before but did not ask the question on here so I have no documentation of how I did so.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy

servers = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\a089673\\Desktop\\lbcsv\\csv\\server.csv', encoding='utf-8', sep=',')
print(servers.head())

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/a089673/Desktop/lbcsv/pandaslb.py", line 4, in <module>
    servers = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\a089673\\Desktop\\lbcsv\\csv\\server.csv', encoding='utf-8', sep=',')
FileNotFoundError: File b'C:\\Users\\a089673\\Desktop\\lbcsv\\csv\\server.csv' does not exist
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: ok just updated it with the error

Comment: In the above example I have one backslash before server, but it makes no difference, still throughs same error.

Comment: Can you paste the entire traceback in your question please?

Comment: Updated the post with the full traceback  says does not exist, which I just took a couple seconds to confirm it indeed does.

Comment: I used all lower case for folders and file names as well.

Comment: It's quite unlikely this has anything to do with pandas.  What does `print(os.path.exists('C:\\Users\\a089673\\Desktop\\lbcsv\\csv\\server.csv'))` return?

Comment: Can you fire up your python interpreter and simply try something like `open('C:\\Users\\a089673\\Desktop\\lbcsv\\csv\\server.csv')`. If that fails, then there's something wrong with the filename.

Comment: I am not seeing an thing in particularly unusual with the path but I have had to use a raw string in some cases. Try this: `r'C:\Users\a089673\Desktop\lbcsv\csv\server.csv'`

Comment: Or try this https://pythonspot.com/pandas-read-csv/  comment the matplotlib import

Comment: Yall were right, something with the path was wrong. Now I get a tokenizing error but will have to research that in the morning.  Something to pull away from this is when you are on tilt, its best to walk away for a bit and come back with fresh eyes. Can not believe I missed that. Appreciate all the help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, `\a` is an escape character and that is causing issue for you. Using raw string as mentioned in the comments solve this issue.

You can see this clearly if you do `repr(file_path)` . This is one of the gotchas with Windows. I would suggest using forward slashes for accessing files even in Windows to avoid running into these issues.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try below code

```
df=pd.read_csv('C:\\\\Users\\\\a089673\\\\Desktop\\\\lbcsv\\\\csv\\\\server.csv')
df
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

Answer was to add the 's' at the end of the file name and to use the \ in the file path.