# import data in python using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, matplotlib, data-science

This is the code that I used to import my data as csv

```
from pandas import read_csv
from matplotlib import pyplot as pltplt
series = read_csv('final.csv', header=0, index_col=0)
```

this is the second one which I tried

```
import csv
with open('people.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

But I found same kind of error like this in both case

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File final.csv does not exist: 'final.csv'
```

Comment: As the error says: `FileNotFoundError: File final.csv does not exist`. The code cannot find the file you've tried to open. Is the file in the same folder that you're launching the script from?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas can't open a csv file FileNotFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48656129/pandas-cant-open-a-csv-file-filenotfounderror)

Answer (score 1):

You could do following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("./Path/where/you/stored/table/data.csv")
print(df)
```

(df stands for data file)

> File final.csv does not exist:

The error that you make is that you don't type in the correct path where the csv is stored. Are you using jupyter?

Comment: thank you, this code really helped me to import my data set.

Answer (score 0):

add the folder csv like `with open('c:\\Users\\admin\\ ..... .csv', 'r') as file:`